# Entity Framework throwing "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker" for anything but version 6.1.3 in Nuget

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

Hi I realise there is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051931/why-is-entity-framework-6-1-3-throwing-a-could-not-load-type-system-data-entit). Firstly the answer proposed was not relevant as I did not have a version in the GAC. I have also tried uninstalling .NET Framework *and* visual studio (2013) with no luck.

For my existing projects using a version of Entity Framework *before* 6.1.3 it gives me the following error when I try and run:

```
{"The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception."}    
Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.":"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker"
```

However they build fine, and if I use 6.1.3 it for some reason works. I know it's unique to my machine as they work on my colleagues' machines. It does this on any project referring to EntityFramework (or EntityFramework.SqlServer). It's as if somewhere there is an older version of EntityFramework.dll, but like I say it's not in the GAC.

The other suggestions have been to uninstall and reinstall with a specific version, and this doesn't work. I can't remember the point in time where it stopped working (as it has been working in the past), although it probably has something to do with me installing VS2015 which I have recently uninstalled, to no avail.

Please let me know if anyone can help or needs more information.

Many thanks.

Comment: I got this issue as well, any findings?

Comment: Unfortunately, I re-imaged my machine in the end! It was something to do with different versions of Visual Studio. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: I got the same issue and I resolved it modifying my csproj file of presentation layer, basically, i updated the version from 6.0.0.0 to 6.1.3.0, it worked for me but after a while, I got the same issue after building a project the csproj file was not updated even