# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx'

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, serialization, mvvm

I have a `MVVM - WPF Browser Application` application using `Entity Framework 6`. I'm trying to delete a row in my dataGrid. I can delete one row, but when I try to delete a second I have this following error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find
>   assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxx'.

### **ViewModelBase:**

```
public class CommandBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region "INotifyPropertyChanged members"
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    //This routine is called each time a property value has been set. 
    //This will //cause an event to notify WPF via data-binding that a change has occurred. 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    private ObservableCollection<T> collection;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            if (collection == null)
            {
                Get();
            }
            return collection;
        }
        set { collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection"); }
    }
    private T _selected;
    public T Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set { _selected = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected"); }
    }
    private ICommand getCommand;
    private ICommand saveCommand;
    private ICommand removeCommand;
    public ICommand GetCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return getCommand ?? (getCommand = new RelayCommand(Get,CanGet));
        }
    }
    protected virtual bool CanGet()
    {
        return true;
    }
    protected virtual void Get()
    {
        //return true;
    }
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
       get
       {
            return saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new RelayCommand(Save, CanSave));
       }
    }
    protected virtual void Save()
    {
        //return true;
    }
    protected virtual bool CanSave()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return removeCommand ?? (removeCommand = new RelayCommand(Delete,CanDelete));
        }
    }
    protected virtual void Delete()
    {
    }
    protected virtual bool CanDelete()
    {
         if (Selected != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

### **ViewModel:**

```
public class SupplierViewModel : CommandBase<foodSupplier>
{
    public Context ctx = new Context();
    protected override void Get()
    {
        ctx.foodSuppliers.ToList().ForEach(supplier => ctx.foodSuppliers.Local.Add(supplier));
        Collection = ctx.foodSuppliers.Local;
    }
    protected override bool CanGet()
    {
        return true;
    }
    protected override void Save()
    {
        foreach (foodSupplier item in Collection)
        {
            if (ctx.Entry(item).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
            {
                ctx.foodSuppliers.Add(item);
            }
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    protected override void Delete()
    {
        var id = Selected;
        var supp = (from s in ctx.foodSuppliers
                where s.idfoodSupplier == id.idfoodSupplier
                select s).SingleOrDefault();
        ctx.foodSuppliers.Remove(supp);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        Collection.Remove(supp);
    }
    protected virtual bool CanDelete()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

### **View:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
          Margin="5"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dataGridTextColumn"
                            Header="Supplier"
                            Binding="{Binding idfoodSupplier, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Visibility="Hidden" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier"
                            Binding="{Binding supplier, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
<Button Height="Auto"
        Width="Auto"
        Content="Delete"
        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
```

### **App.config:**

```
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="xx" connectionString="xxx" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you install EF6 via NuGet?

Comment: Yep, I can display update and sometimes delete a row.

Comment: When you debug the application, where exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: at ctx.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

I have fully tested your code, and it is working fine deleting all 5 rows, even the last row.

Your code needs selecting a row first, make sure you are selecting a row in DataGrid and then deleting the row. You can disable your command button and enable it only if user selects a row in DataGrid.

I made following changes to your code :

```
public ICommand GetCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return getCommand ?? (getCommand = new RelayCommand(p=>this.Get(), p=>this.CanGet()));
            }
        }
```

Like so in other commands too :

```
return saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new RelayCommand(p=>this.Save(), p=>this.CanSave()));
```

and in

```
return removeCommand ?? (removeCommand = new RelayCommand(p=>this.Delete(), p=>this.CanDelete()));
```

Second solution could be :

Open

Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console

then run

install-package entityframework -version 6.0.0.0

Try solutions posted here :

[Why is Entity Framework 6.1.3 throwing a "Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051931/why-is-entity-framework-6-1-3-throwing-a-could-not-load-type-system-data-entit)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made sure a row is selected and I followed the changes you made, but still have the same error.

Comment: no, same same. I added the App.config in my Question. Perhaps I should specify my application is a WPF Browser Application.

Comment: further improved the answer

Comment: ok, my error should come from the fact I don't have the Entityframework.dll in the GAC. But when uninstall and install, nothing is created in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue occur under a random context.  For example, yesterday I ran Windows Update and installed 27 additional updates.  The next day this error started being thrown every 15 mins or so.  The software that was running didn't change.

Seems Windows update was waiting on a pending restart.  Making sure the server was happy, this error just went away...