# MVC Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC Web Application runs fine on my local copy. When I transfer it to a server, I get the following error. I have tried everything including creating a new project.

The exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Description: `An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

Exception Details: `System.Exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Source Error:

`An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

Stack Trace:

```
[Exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   TotalDeskMVCVer4.Controllers.HomeController.Index(UserCustom model) in d:\Websites\5. Stand Alone Applications\TotalDeskMVCVer4\TotalDeskMVCVer4\Controllers\HomeController.cs:128
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9667432
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

**Edit**

This is the code that throws the error

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TotalDesk.UserCustom model)
    {
        try
        {
            string strUsername = RADBase.Utils.Encryption.Encrypt(model.Username);
            string strPassword = RADBase.Utils.Encryption.Encrypt(model.Password);

            RADSystem rad = new RADSystem();
            TotalDeskMVCVer4.Models.User user = new TotalDeskMVCVer4.Models.User();
            user = rad.Users.Where(u => u.Username == strUsername && u.Password == strPassword).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
            {
                return Redirect("~/");

                Branch branch = rad.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID == user.BranchID.Value).FirstOrDefault();
                Company objComp = rad.Companies.Where(c => c.CompanyID == branch.CompanyID.Value).FirstOrDefault();

                UserPersonal upersonal = rad.UserPersonals.Where(up => up.UserID == user.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
                Personal objPers = rad.Personals.Where(p => p.PersonalID == upersonal.PersonalID).FirstOrDefault();

                Profile.SetPropertyValue("UserID", user.UserID);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("SecurityLevelID", user.SecurityLevelID);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("UserGroupID", user.UserGroupID);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("BranchID", user.BranchID);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("CompanyID", objComp.CompanyID);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("CompanyName", objComp.CompanyName);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("UserFullName", objPers.FirstName + " " + objPers.Surname);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("HasFullControl", user.HasFullControl.Value);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("HasWritePermission", user.HasWritePermission.Value);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("HasModifyPermission", user.HasModifyPermission.Value);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("IsReadOnly", user.IsReadOnly.Value);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("HasLicense", user.HasAcceptedTC.Value);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("SelectedCompanyID", objComp.CompanyID);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("JobTitle", objPers.Occupation);
                Profile.SetPropertyValue("JoinDate", user.DateCreated.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

                Profile.Save();

                //RAD.Util.LogActivity("Logged In", Profile.UserID);

                HttpCookie cooke = new HttpCookie("RADUserEmail");
                cooke.Value = model.Username;
                cooke.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                Response.Cookies.Add(cooke);

                HttpCookie cookeRM = new HttpCookie("RADUserRM");
                if (model.IsActive.Value)
                {
                    HttpCookie cookeR = new HttpCookie("RADUserP");
                    cookeR.Value = strPassword;
                    cookeR.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookeR);

                    cookeRM.Value = "1";
                    cookeRM.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookeRM);
                }
                else
                {
                    cookeRM.Value = "0";
                    cookeRM.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookeRM);
                }

                if (user.IsActive.Value)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Remove("RADUserEmail");
            Response.Cookies.Remove("RADUserRM");
            Response.Cookies.Remove("RADUserP");
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

        return Redirect("~/");
    }
```

**Edit 2**

Full Exception

```
 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices..ctor()
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices..cctor()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.get_Instance()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
  at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.MemberInfoExtensions.GetValue(MemberInfo memberInfo)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(Type providerType)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.TryGetInstance(String providerTypeName)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterSqlServerProvider()
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t)
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
  at TotalDeskMVCVer4.Models.RADSystem..ctor()
  at TotalDeskMVCVer4.Controllers.HomeController.Index(UserCustom model)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices..ctor()
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices..cctor()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.get_Instance()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
  at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.MemberInfoExtensions.GetValue(MemberInfo memberInfo)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(Type providerType)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.TryGetInstance(String providerTypeName)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterSqlServerProvider()
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t)
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
  at TotalDeskMVCVer4.Models.RADSystem..ctor()
  at TotalDeskMVCVer4.Controllers.HomeController.Index(UserCustom model)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.get_Instance()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.MemberInfoExtensions.GetValue(MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.GetInstance(Type providerType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ProviderServicesFactory.TryGetInstance(String providerTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterSqlServerProvider()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.RegisterDbProviderServices()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.InitializeLazyInternalContext(IInternalConnection internalConnection, DbCompiledModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at TotalDeskMVCVer4.Models.RADSystem..ctor()
   at TotalDeskMVCVer4.Controllers.HomeController.Index(UserCustom model)]
   TotalDeskMVCVer4.Controllers.HomeController.Index(UserCustom model) +1547
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9667432
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: I'm still battling with this. it's been 2 weeks and I can't get this system to run on the server :(

Comment: Busy installing Visual Studio on my Server to see if I can debug it from there. Will post updates if successful.

Comment: Show the code where the error is said to be thrown.

Comment: @Nkosi  Please see edit above with code that throws error. It works perfectly on my local copy though.

Comment: [Have you seen this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648113/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-error-mscorlib) It's older, but it may point you in the right direction.

Comment: @TimothyG. I have seen that question. I've searched SO and the web for days on end. This same code works on my local machine. That's what beats me. Only on the server it's throwing this error.

Comment: I believe SetProperty is using reflection. The target server might not be allowing this operation to be performed by application. This might need an elevated permission account under which the application should be running. Did you try having the app pool of the application having networkservice identity?

Comment: Any reason you are not setting the values to properties directly but using reflection for it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I've commented all Profile.SetPropertyValue code and it still throws the same error

Comment: Its good if what exception is being thrown is understood. Do you log the exception in the application? Can log the exception in the catch block before rethrowing it and share the message of it and stack trace of it? Line 128 is I believe is in the catch block. If not csn you tell what is the code at line 128?

Comment: Which EF version being installed? If it is version 6, try every solution provided with similar issue there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051931/why-is-entity-framework-6-1-3-throwing-a-could-not-load-type-system-data-entit. Check your csproj file, GAC and connection string value to make sure.

Comment: I am using version 6. I removed version 5 and added ver 6 as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I found that the GAC version of Entity Framework was different from my project version.  Replaced the Project version with GAC version and now I have a different error. But I moved forward from the last error.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Which error caught up next? Edit your question for clarity between thrown exceptions, and help yourself avoid getting DVs due to insufficent details.