# Migration Ef 6 in project class Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Project Data:
I have a Class Library project that contains EF 6.0. In it, I have my contexts and my models.
However, when I use migrations to add a new table with the Add-Migration command, it throws an exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.TableExistenceChecker' from
>   assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: You may need to parameterize your `add-migration` command. Something like `add-migration migrationName -StartupProjectName MyStartupProjectWithConnectString`. Also, make sure the library class is selected in the console.

Comment: I used command
`add-migration -ProjectName "DataProject" -StartUpProjectName "WebProject" -ConnectionString "NameOfConnectionStringInWebConfigWebProject" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"'`
and so the error persists.

Class Project: DataProject in Class Library.

Web project: WebProject in MVC 5

Comment: Maybe try these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051931/why-is-entity-framework-6-1-3-throwing-a-could-not-load-type-system-data-entit